# setting listener Combobox JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, interface, listener

Hi i have a problem with some Combo box. I have an interface with four combo boxes and they use as Items the same list. I added a listener to one of those combo boxes and i wanted the listener to be done just when i select an item and not when the list is changed, but with this listener he automaticalli runs again when i remove an item from the list

```
            class1.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( (options, oldValue, newValue) ->{

            System.out.println(oldValue);
            System.out.println(newValue);

            class1.getItems().add(oldValue);
            class1.getItems().remove(newValue);

            });
```

so at the end he runs this listener every time i do the remove, and it ends with an error eventually

Comment: If you remove the item that is selected, then clearly the selection will have to change. What are you actually wanting to happen here? (Why are you changing the list on a change in the selection?)

Comment: I would like to show on the comboBox Value the item that i selected but i wanted that item to be removed from the list, so when i will click again that combo box it will show as options all but the one that is already selected

Answer (score 0):

The problem basically arises because you end up changing an observable list (the selection model's `selectedItems`) while a change in that list is being processed. This is something of a flaw in the API, imo. A workaround (hack) is to use a filtered list, and update the predicate on the list in a `Platform.runLater(...)`, so as to let the first change complete before changing it again:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxNoSelectedItem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> allItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>();
        combo.setValue(allItems.get(0));
        FilteredList<String> items = allItems.filtered(item -> item != combo.getValue());
        combo.setItems(items);

        combo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> Platform.runLater(() -> items.setPredicate(item -> item != newValue)));


        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(combo);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Maybe a cleaner approach is just to disable the cell displaying the currently selected item, which is close to, but not quite the same, UX:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxNoSelectedItem extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> allItems = FXCollections.observableArrayList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>(allItems);

        combo.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

            {
                disableProperty().bind(combo.valueProperty().isEqualTo(itemProperty()));
            }

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                setText(item);
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setTop(combo);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok this works but for some reasons on the first two or three changes deletes even other elements.. after a while it works perfectly but i end losing two or three items from the list

Comment: FilteredList<String> items = classi.filtered(item -> item != class1.getValue());
        class1.setItems(items);

        class1.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> Platform.runLater(() -> items.setPredicate(item -> item != newValue)));